# PhpStorm search and replace multiple times between two strings

Tags: regex, replace, phpstorm

In PhpStorm IDE, using the search and replace feature, I'm trying to add `.jpg` to all strings between quotes that come after `$colorsfiles = [` and before the closing `]`.

```
$colorsfiles = ["Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Black", "White", "Golden", "Green", "Purple", "Yellow", "cyan", "Gray", "Pink", "Brown", "Sky Blue", "Silver"];
```

If the `"abc"` is not in between `$colorsfiles = [` and `]`, there should be no replacement.

The regex that I'm using is

```
$colorsfiles = \[("(\w*?)", )*
```

and replace string is

```
$colorsfiles = ["$2.jpg"]
```

The current result is

```
$colorsfiles = ["Brown.jpg"]"Sky Blue", "Silver"];
```

While the expected output is

```
$colorsfiles = ["Blue.jpg", "Red.jpg", "Orange.jpg", "Black.jpg", "White.jpg", "Golden.jpg", "Green.jpg", "Purple.jpg", "Yellow.jpg", "cyan.jpg", "Gray.jpg", "Pink.jpg", "Brown.jpg", "Sky Blue.jpg", "Silver.jpg"];
```

Comment: so you want to add `.jpg` to each of the array elements?

Comment: this doesn't look like a regular expression to me `\[("(\w*?)", )*`  I tried fixing the question as best I could but your missing the quotes and `/` delimiters.  Also you don't show how you implement `preg_replace()`,-note-  you can't use an array as the subject (3rd argument) has to be a string.

Comment: why not just `array_map(function($value) {
    return $value.'.jpg';
}, $colorsfiles);`

Comment: I think you don't understand what it is that `[` and `]` mean. They are part of PHP syntax, not a string. None of the code you've provided here would be parsed at all except the first line.

Comment: @AtaurRahman bro i can't do this in php because i'm trying to acheive this replacement in IDE

Comment: @subroutines yes brother exactly this is what i'm trying to do

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix brother kindly open eyes and see this is regex and search is working fine. I attempted this in phpSTORM IDE and output is not as expected that's why i post this question for help here

Comment: @miken32 i'm doing this in IDE PHPSTORM it's part of regex and i'm  escaping this too :)

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to explain that you are attempting to work with code within a text editor. Because it absolutely does not say that now.

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)",\s*"|\$colorsfiles\s*=\s*\[")\K[^"]+` and replace with `$0.jpg`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1144wI/1). A version without `\K` - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/1144wI/2), search for `(\G(?!^)",\s*"|\$colorsfiles\s*=\s*\[")([^"]+)` and replace with `$1$2.jpg`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks alot brother <3

Comment: So, which one works in PhpStorm? Both?

Comment: All answers below are based on the assumption you only have one string like you posted in your input. Is it true? Please update your question if you plan to *only* replace values inside `"`  inside the brackets *after* `$colorsfiles=`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes both works

Comment: I added an answer below. Can't add full pattern details as I'm on a mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(\G(?!^)",\s*"|\$colorsfiles\s*=\s*\[")([^"]+)
```

and replace with `$1$2.jpg`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1144wI/2).

The regex matches `$colorsfiles = ["` or the end of the previous match followed with `","` while capturing these texts into Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` placeholder) and then captures into Group 2 (later referred to with `$2`) one or more chars other than a double quotation mark.

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^)",\s*"|\$colorsfiles\s*=\s*\[")` -

  - `\G(?!^)",\s*"` - the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`), `",` substring, 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) and a `"` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\$colorsfiles\s*=\s*\["` - `$colorsfiles`, 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`), `=`, 0+ whitespaces, `["` (note that `$` and `[` must be escaped to match literal chars)
- `([^"]+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more (`+`) chars other than `"` (the negated character class, `[^"]`)

Answer (score 1):

why you need regex for this? a simple [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will do the trick for you.

```
<?php
function addExtension($color)
{
    return $color.".jpg";
}
$colorsfiles = ["Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Black", "White", "Golden", "Green", "Purple", "Yellow", "cyan", "Gray", "Pink", "Brown", "Sky Blue", "Silver"];
$colorsfiles_with_extension = array_map("addExtension", $colorsfiles);
print_r($colorsfiles_with_extension);
?>
```

**Edit:** I've tested it on my **PhpStorm**, let's do it like

**search**:

```
"([a-zA-Z\s]+)"
```

**replace_all**:

```
"$1.jpg"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to acheive this replacement in ide not in php

Comment: @Nandlasb I've **Edited** my answer. Have a look again :) and let me know is it working or not perfectly?

Comment: Brother it is still working but on both array i have same array as this one :(

Comment: @Nandlasb If you have more than one array in the file where you want to do such replacement -- select it and also tick `In Selection` option (shown on screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

*You should have said that you're trying it on IDE*

Even though I don't use PHPStorm, I'm posting solution tested on my NetBeans.

Find :    `"([\w ]+)"([\,\]]{1})`
Replace : `"$1\.jpg"$2`

Comment: This one is not working because i have two arrays having same content

Comment: So you want to apply change to only one array?

Comment: @Nandlasb If you have more than one array in the file where you want to do such replacement -- select it and also tick `In Selection` option (it's visible on screenshot in another answer)

Comment: as i mentioned this array "$colorsfiles ="

Comment: You would need to replace it one by one instead of "replace all" then.....